# idxmax and .loc with multiindex dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a multiindex dataframe based on the maximum values of another multiindex dataframe. Here are the two dataframes:

**df1**

```
               Month1 Month2 Month3 .... 
Long Lat
0.0. 90.       20.     2.     12.0
     89.75.    15.     3.     14.0
```

**df2**

```
               Month1 Month2 Month3 .... 
Long Lat
0.0. 90.       14.8     13.8     14.5
     89.75.    12.3     12.2     11.2
```

`max_vals = df1.idxmax(axis=1)` gives the following:

```
Long Lat
0.0. 90.       Month1
     89.75.    Month1
```

And then
`combined_dfs = df2.loc[df1]`

gives the following error:

`KeyError: ['Month1' 'Month1'] not in index`

I would like the output to be:

```
               Month
Long Lat
0.0. 90.       14.8 
     89.75.    12.3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `reindex` `df2` with the indices and column names obtained from `idxmax`; then use `numpy.diag` to get the max values in each location in `df1`:

```py
import numpy as np
max_pos = df1.idxmax(axis=1)
out = np.diag(df2.reindex(columns=max_pos, index=max_pos.index))
```

Output:

```py
array([14.8, 12.3])
```